# How to send multiple images into REST API

Tags: php, mysql, json, rest, codeigniter

I'm taking multiple documents of candidate from database, put it into one array and sending this array and some other additional information to the REST API. Then it's throwing an exception `FILE Type NOT Support`. When sending single image it works properly.

```
foreach($a_files as $a_file)
{
    $file_name_with_full_path=$a_file->uploaded_path.$a_file->document_name;
    $mime_type=mime_content_type($file_name_with_full_path);
    $cFile[] = '@'.realpath($file_name_with_full_path).';type='.$mime_type.';';
}
```

Sending this information through REST API.  My post data is like:

```
$post= array('level'     => "level",
    'nameOfInstitute'    => "nameOfInstitute",
    'nameAsPerDocument'  => "nameAsPerDocument",
    'issueDate'          => "issueDate",
    'registrationNumber' => "registrationNumber",
    'yearOfPassing'      =>"yearofpassing",
    'degree'             =>"degree",
    'fieldOfStudy'       =>"fieldofstudy",
    'grade'              =>"grade",
    'nameOfBoardUniversity'=>"university",
    'file'                 =>$cFile
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: multipart/form-data'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $val);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$target_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
$response = curl_exec ($ch);
$err = curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

It's throwing an exception `file type not supported`. But when sending single file, it's working fine (without loop). What is the problem in above code when sending multiple files in the API. Please help me out from this problem.

Comment: Have you checked that the API definitely supports sending multiple images - and specifically, sending them in that exact data format? The name of the parameter `'file'` (singular) suggests it maybe only expects one file. Is there any documentation?

Comment: P.S. As far as I can see, your `$cFile[]` array doesn't contain files anyway, it simple contains a list of file names and mime types. That is not the same as sending actual file data. So it's not clear really what you are trying to achieve by that. Maybe you can also show us the version of your code which works sending a single file?

Comment: To me, it looks like the file field is simply not meant to store multiple files. You'll probably have to run one request for each file you're trying to send.

Comment: When i'm trying in postman its working properly.In documentation it specify that file takes array type.

Comment: then you need to show us precisely what you did in PostMan, because evidently it isn't equivalent to what you're doing now. And we could do with seeing the relveant bit of the documentation. P.S. Did you know that PostMan can auto-generate your PHP/cURL code for you?

Comment: When i'm using this below code, last file is getting overwritten.     
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array('level' => 'TENTH_STD','nameOfInstitute' => 'ndfdf','nameAsPerDocument' => 'snffndsfds','issueDate' => '2020-05-01','registrationNumber' => 'sss213213','file'=> new CURLFILE('/E:/Work/H_M/celio.pdf'),'file'=> new CURLFILE('/E:/Work/H_M/User Stories for Onboarding Module - ANSR-H&M Services Private Limited.pdf')),

Comment: Please don't post code in the comments. As you can see, it's very hard to read. Your question has an "edit" button below it. Please use that to update your main question text with any additional information you want to give us.

Comment: Anyway yes, that would obviously overwrite it because you're specifying the same field name multiple times - how is PHP supposed to tell them apart, do you imagine? You'd need an array of CURLFILE objects. Try something like `'file'=> array(new CURLFILE('/E:/Work/H_M/celio.pdf'),new CURLFILE('/E:/Work/H_M/User Stories for Onboarding Module - ANSR-H&M Services Private Limited.pdf'))`

Comment: CURLFILE won't support in my php version

Comment: Huh? Above you said it was overwriting the last one, now you say it doesn't work at all?? That makes no sense. What actual error are you seeing, if you try the code I've just suggested? And what version of PHP do you have? It has existed since PHP 5.5 as per the documentation. The only [supported versions](https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php) of PHP now are 7.2 or above.

Comment: Above mentioned code are from postman.Instead of CURLFILE,i'm using same key multiple times,that time it got overwrite.

Comment: version using php 5.4

Comment: then you need to **urgently** upgrade your PHP. You haven't been getting support or security updates for almost 5 years!! See https://www.php.net/eol.php. That is far too much time to run an unsupported version, there is really no excuse for it. You are just leaving your code and servers vulnerable. And also you can't take advantage of newer functionality like CURLFILE either